# How to send session request with cookies via curl?

Tags: php

I want to send a request using curl for session and cookie to a URL on my server. But click can't be counted.

http://requestsite.com/sessionverify.php

And sessionverify.php redirects to a URL which updates the request. The redirect URL of sessionverify.php is http://requestsite.com/click.php

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out what's being done in click.php page, maybe there is some sort of javascript code. Take a look to it and the HTTP traffic generated by this page. Certainly you'll have to emulate its functionality with PHP.